# Clone selected option inside another div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have a selectable tree, where i have users, then i want to select them on the left, then click on the button "right" and send it to the right side div, and if i need to remove it from the right side, i want to select it on the right side and click the button "left".

I'm trying for over 2 days but i dont have any idea how to start, can someone help me?

Here's the jsfiddle working, hope that helps understanding.

This its what i have from jquery so far:

```
$(function () {
    $('#jstree1').jstree({
        "plugins": ["wholerow", "checkbox"]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JC9gM/

To understand better what i need, here's a example, but i need with the jsTree plugin:

Working example: http://www.akchauhan.com/examples/example01/

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I did something wrong? if i did, i'm sorry, really.

Comment: Questions should be easy to understand and recreate, the minimal needed code to recreate the issue should be added to the Question. Your link might go down one day and the question not much understandable to anyone in the future.

Comment: Oh ok, i'll edit it with a JSfiddle. thanks buddy, i really didnt know that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem with this plugin [multiselect.js](http://loudev.com/). It is easy to use and if you do not need it to look like a tree, it will work.

```
<select id="users" multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="1">
        <option>1.A</option>
        <optgroup label="1.B">
            <option>1.B.I</option>
            <option>1.B.II</option>
        </optgroup>
    </optgroup>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
<script>
    $('#users').multiSelect({
        selectableOptgroup: true
    });
</script>
```

Check out the "optgroup" in Demos section to see it working

Comment: Hi there, thanks for reply, i really need it like a tree only at the left side :(